# getBoundingClientRect() Object properties cannot be copied

Tags: javascript, getboundingclientrect

```
function test(o) {
    console.log("Object:", o);
    console.log("Assign test:", Object.assign({}, o));
    console.log("Keys test:", Object.keys(o));
    console.log("JSON test:", JSON.stringify(o));
}

var el = document.getElementById("question");                 /* or document.body */

test(el.style);                                               /* works as expected */
test(el.getBoundingClientRect());                             /* behaves like {} */
test(Object.assign(el.getBoundingClientRect(),{aaaa: 1111})); /* works... only for aaaa */
```

Why?

#### Output (test results)

See [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/raw/rCT1wRGr).

#### MDN documentation

1. [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)
2. [DOMRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMClientRect)

Comment: Can you add the outputs here?

Comment: @MertAkcakaya: I'm trying to add output but StackOverflow prevents it with message “It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.” ☹ Therefore I posted it on PasteBin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Object.assign` and `Object.keys` are working with **own** enumerable properties. `DOMRect` properties are inherited from `DOMRectPrototype` and cannot be accessed by those methods.

You can prove that by:

```
let rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
rect.hasOwnProperty('x');                        // === false
Object.getPrototypeOf(rect).hasOwnProperty('x'); // === true
```

I used Lodash `_.assignIn` which iterates over **own and inherited** source properties:

https://jsfiddle.net/msazmfxo/

***UPDATE***

Based on this answer, [7vujy0f0hy found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713229/why-are-properties-of-this-object-domrect-inaccessible-to-standard-javascript/42714159?noredirect=1#comment72552916_42714159) the acceptable [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/esheytbu/):

```
var ownify = input => 
               Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(input)).reduce((output,key) => 
                 Object.assign(output, {[key]: input[key]}), Object.assign({}, input));

test(ownify(el.getBoundingClientRect())); /* apparently works! */
```

(Although it iterates only over one level of inheritance, attributes from deeper levels will be still missing)

Comment: Very nice function, this `_.assignIn`! I wish it were native. I replaced `o.x` in your Fiddle with `o.width` which is a property coincidentally extant both in `CSSStyleDeclaration` and `DOMRect`. Also, contrary to MDN, `DOMRect` in my Chrome (Windows) lacks properties `x` and `y`. Here’s [my fork](https://jsfiddle.net/7n11vt7r/) of your Fiddle, along with some other improvements for educational value. P.S. The correct spelling is “prove” (verb), not “proof” (noun).

Comment: [Even better Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7L82r3b9/4/). I reverted `function test()` to the original form and instead added a fourth call: `test(_.assignIn({}, el.getBoundingClientRect())); /* just works! */` in the main code.

Comment: Based on your post, I created a function `ownify()` that takes an object `input` and returns a new object `output` that _owns_ all inherited properties of the old object `input`. See [new Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/esheytbu/). I wish an accepted solution contained this function (if it has no flaw). Can we add it to your answer?